# How start the debugger in RStudio for Python Code

Tags: python, debugging, rstudio, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment and want to use python code in RStudio.
However It is not clear for me how to start debugging?
If i switch to Python Code I cannot set any breakpoints. If i switch back to R Code it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not yet RStudio native to set breakpoints and debug Python code there.

But I found ipdb which is an iterative python debugger that can be imported and used in RStudio.

Here is how: https://hasil-sharma.github.io/2017-05-13-python-ipdb/